# Is it true that new users are not able to upvote answers on their own question?

Tags: support

Recently I found several times a comment from a new user like

> Sorry I can't upvote your answer, because I don't have enough reps.

Is that true?

Comment: Yep, it's true. Wanna post a feature request about it on [meta.se]? (it might be a duplicate though..)

Comment: @Seth thx, **now** I was able to find it on the privileges page - no I guess it wouldn't be too useful after all - and the good answer was not always from me, so it still got it's due upvote :-)

Comment: A similar question was already asked on MSO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote And it's accepted answer makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its true. You need 15 reputation to vote up and 125 to vote down. This has been specified in the [help center page for privileges](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges).